# In Facebook app, is there a way to link directly to "join a group"

Tags: php, facebook

I'd like to have a link for a user to join a Facebook group from within my Facebook application.

Here is the link on Facebook's "display a group" page (minus a longer referrer part), but the group id is encrypted:

http://www.new.facebook.com/group.php?sid=c431b3cfc02765def331081f8b71ffbd

Anyone know how to either encrypt a group id the Facebook way or otherwise build a link that adds a user to a group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just use the group id?

This works for me:
[http://www.new.facebook.com/group.php?gid={ID}](http://www.new.facebook.com/group.php?gid=%7BID%7D)

Comment: This takes them out of your app back to Facebook. We want them to stay in our app but allow them to join a group that is displayed on the page.

Comment: Did you get any solution to accomplish this? if so can you please provide me with the headsup of what direction should i follow. thanks :)